# How to convert a T-SQL query into a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am running `SQL Server 2012` and I need to convert a `T-SQL` query into a `Stored Procedure`. My aim is to run a `SQL` job that will execute this `Stored Procedure` on a daily basis.

My `T-SQL` query stands as follows:

```
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @TableHead VARCHAR(1000),
    @TableTail VARCHAR(1000)

SET @TableTail = '</table></body></html>' ;
SET @TableHead = '<html><head>' + '<style>'
    + 'td {border: solid black;border-width: 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font: 11px arial} '
    + '</style>' + '</head>' + '<body>' + 'Report generated on : '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 106) 
    + ' <br> <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' 
    + '<tr> <td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>StayYear</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Market</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jan</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Feb</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Mar</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Apr</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>May</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jun</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jul</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Aug</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Sep</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Oct</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Nov</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Dec</b></td>';

SET @Body = ( SELECT *
              FROM  View1               
                FOR   XML RAW('tr'),
                      ELEMENTS
            )


SELECT  @Body = @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail
```

What are the steps to convert the above into a `Stored Procedure`?

Comment: What are the input parameters? And output is in form of table?

Comment: Are you saying you found no information about how to create stored procedure in MS SQL SERVER?

Comment: This is not something I would do in SQL anyway. This is something that needs to be done on the presentation layer. Your SQL only need to retrieve the data.

Comment: Given that the last step is to set a variable, your code doesn't do anything useful no matter how you wrap it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @DanBracuk Ok, may be I am missing something here. The idea is that the SQL codes above represent the HTML body part of an email that needs to be executed by the Stored Procedure. The input is SELECT * from View1 and the output will be formatted by the codes I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Not much to elaborate on - SQL Server should not care about HTML/CSS/JS stuff at all, it should only return data. You use your application to generate HTML/css/js from that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can add make your script as a Stored Procedure by simply binding your Query inside a `Create Procedure` statement. Like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Database Schema>.<Procedue Name>
AS
BEGIN
   <Your Script>
END
```

you can copy and paste your Query between the `BEGIN` and `END`.

Like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sProc_MyProc
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @TableHead VARCHAR(1000),
    @TableTail VARCHAR(1000)

SET @TableTail = '</table></body></html>' ;
SET @TableHead = '<html><head>' + '<style>'
    + 'td {border: solid black;border-width: 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font: 11px arial} '
    + '</style>' + '</head>' + '<body>' + 'Report generated on : '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 106) 
    + ' <br> <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' 
    + '<tr> <td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>StayYear</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Market</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jan</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Feb</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Mar</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Apr</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>May</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jun</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jul</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Aug</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Sep</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Oct</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Nov</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Dec</b></td>';

SET @Body = ( SELECT *
              FROM  View1               
                FOR   XML RAW('tr'),
                      ELEMENTS
            )


SELECT  @Body = @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail

END
```

Comment: FYI:Procedure has no schema ,i am talking about this part `<Procecude Schema>`\

Comment: @TheGameiswar, if one wants to write an SP in a schema other than dbo, one can.  I do it quite regularly.

Comment: The BEGIN/END is not required to surround the stored procedure body.

Comment: Right, but you will need to say `SELECT  @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail` as last statement or you need to add `SELECT @Body` before the end. Otherwise, the SP will not return any resultset and the content of @Body is lost after the execution. Also, you might want to add some parameters (e.g. filter criteria).

Comment: @Matt Thanks. You saved me a headache!

Comment: @DanBracuk Earlier edit was something in the lines of procedure schema,procedure doesn't have it's own schema..but of course you can write one

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply right-click *'Stored Procedures'* and click *'Stored Procedure'*.

   [image]

   A new window will open with some very basic code.

   [image]
2. Delete the stuff in green
3. Name your Stored Procedure, with no spaces in the name of the SProc.
4. Paste your SQL script in between the `BEGIN` and `END` clauses.

   [image]
5. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile your Sproc.
6. If everything is setup correctly, you will get a message that reads

   > `Command(s) completed successfully.`